# issue in disabling dates on datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker, vue.js, vuejs2, momentjs

I am using `vue-date-range` date picker. Here I am using `disabledStart` and `disabledEnd` props but its not disabling date on view. For disabling date it required an object. I am passing the object but it doesn't work.I don't know what is the correct object format for disabling the dates.

Any help would be appreciated
Plugin link
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-date-range

Here is **HTML**

```
  <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                <label>When is it required?</label>
                 <daterange class="calendar" 
                  :sync-range.sync="range" 
                  :disable-days-before-today="disableDaysBeforeToday"
                  :days-disabled-start="disableStart"
                  :days-disabled-end="disableEnd"
                  :lang="lang" @change="onChange">
                  </daterange> 
              </div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
import { DateRange } from 'vue-date-range';
export default {


  data() {
    return {
      lang: 'en',
      disableDaysBeforeToday: true,
      disableStart: { startDate:moment()},
      disableEnd: {
       endDate: moment().add(7, 'days')
      },
      range: {}
    }

  },
  components: {
    'daterange': DateRange
  },

  methods: {

    onChange(range) {
      console.log("START", range.startDate._d);
      console.log("END", range.endDate._d);
    },
    disable() {
      console.log("on button click disable dates");
      this.disableStart._d = new Date('2017-08-25').toString()


    }


  }


}
</script>
```

Comment: Seems the `days-disables-start` and `days-disabled-end` should simply be `moment.js` dates, eg `disabledStart: moment()`

Comment: Thanks it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45790389/issue-in-disabling-dates-on-datepicker/45791503#comment78540105_45790389) pointed out, after looking into the [source code of this library](https://github.com/ParadeTo/vue-date-range/blob/master/src/Calendar.vue#L203-L214), I can confirm that the object used is `moment.js`'s date object.
So just pass `moment.js`'s date object to `days-disabled-start` and `days-disabled-end`.

See [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/choasia/y3s9t5g5/) below.

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#range',
    components: {
        'daterange':daterange.DateRange
    },
    data() {
      return {
        lang: 'en',
        range: {
          startDate: moment(),
          endDate: moment().add(2, 'days')
        },
        disableStart: moment().add(3, 'days'),
        disableEnd: moment().add(6, 'days')
      };
    },
    methods: {
      onChange(range) {
        this.range = range;
      },
      setRange (p) {
        if (typeof p === 'number') {
          console.log(p)
          this.range = {
            startDate: moment().add(p, 'days'),
            endDate: moment()
          }
        }
      },
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-date-range@2.2.2/dist/vue-date-range.min.js"></script>
<div id="range" class="calendar-wrapper">
    <span>{{range.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')}}</span>~<span>{{range.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')}}</span>
    <daterange class="calendar" 
      :sync-range="range" 
      :lang="lang" 
      :days-disabled-start="disableStart"
      :days-disabled-end="disableEnd"
      @change="onChange">
    </daterange>
    <button @click.stop.prevent="setRange(-7)">Last 7 days</button>
    <button @click.stop.prevent="setRange(-30)">Last 1 month</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.. it worked.. but why you remove `.sync` in :sync-range.sync`

Comment: i have received date in this format `2017-08-24` how it can convert into moment object so that it can disable

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad Hi, I didn't remove that deliberately, I just picked up an 
 example showed in its repo's readme and no `sync` used there.

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad Hi! Check the doc here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/

Comment: if i have initialize `disableStart: {}` this it automatically disable all dates as first i want to initialize no disable dates then on load to disable dates

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad How about set both `disableStart` and `disableEnd` to `null` or extremely large date?

Comment: null would be better Thanks

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad Glad it helped

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152423/discussion-between-wasiq-muhammad-and-choasia).